# working at the same java project remotely?

Tags: java, ide

Some teacher give to us a group project and i need to work on this project with another guy and we would like to set up a kind of an online repository to be able to commit, revert etc..

Is there a free online tool to do this without having to set up a complicated remote versioning server?

We are using eclipse and java 8.

Thanks

Comment: you can always create your own repository. not sure about github, but I thought bitbucket had a free way to share a repo. You can also set-up an svn repo

Answer (score 2):

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) offers an unlimited number of private repositories for small teams. Of course, basic knowledge of git is necessary